# Getting error 15999 "invalid operator '$sqrt' when using MongoDB aggregation in 3.2

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

According to the docs, the $sqrt operator is new in MongoDB 3.2. I've just upgraded my entire cluster to version 3.2.1 (confirmed by Cloud Manager), but I still can't use $sqrt is my aggregation steps. I'm probably missing something really obvious, so would use a second opinion before reporting a bug to MongoDB.

The step is:

```
{
  "$project": {
    "word": "$indices.text",
    "mult": {"$sqrt": "$indicesSize"}
  }
```

Update: Just found this in my `mongos.log`:

`2016-05-08T18:00:37.616+0200 W SHARDING [Balancer] multiVersion cluster detected, my version is 3.0.11`

So I guess there's a node somewhere still running the old version - maybe an arbiter...

Comment: What's the data type for the field `$indicesSize`, is there any chance there could be non-positive numbers being stored in that field?

Comment: They should all be NumberInt but I tried replaced $indicesSize with 2 and got the same error. My guess is that the mongos still thinks the cluster has nodes running 2.0 version

Comment: Are you running this aggregation pipeline from the client or server? What happens if you try to execute it on mongo shell, and if running from a client, perhaps the app is still connecting to an older enough version of the server??

Comment: Tried both via the Java driver and the mongo client. My local mongo client is 3.2.1 and cluster running 3.2.6. In theory all nodes report as 3.2.6 according to Cloud Manager. Maybe I need to do something on the config servers to finish the 3.0 to 3.2 upgrade?